# _tkinter.TclError: wrong # args : What's the matter?

Tags: python, events, binding, canvas, tkinter

Still writing a game. This error's a little different, though. I get a trace back like this...

`Exception in Tkinter callback
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/tkinter/__init__.py", 
 line 1399, in __call__
 return self.func(*args)
 File "/Users/bluedragon1223/Desktop/Djambi0-2.py", line 68, in _newSpaceChosen
 pieceID = event.widget.find_withtag(currentCommand)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/tkinte/__init__.py",

 line2199, in find_withtag
 return self.find('withtag', tagOrId)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/tkinter/__init__.py", 
 line 2173, in find
 self.tk.call((self._w, 'find') + args)) or ()
 _tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be ".23215664 find withtag tagOrId"`

I mean, I thought the code innocuous enough.

I have global variables `currentCommand = None` and `(CurX, CurY) = (0,0)` and `(ToX, ToY) = (0,0)` to start with, if that has something to do with it, but the main problem is my events.

There are two:

```
def _newSpaceChosen(event):
print(event.widget.find_withtag('rN')) #Used to check if I had used find_withtag correctly
pieceID = event.widget.find_withtag(currentCommand) #This is the problem source
[CurX, CurY] = event.widget.coords(pieceID[1])
print(CurX, CurY)
[MetaToX, MetaToY] = _point2square(event.x, event.y)
print(event.x, event.y)
print(MetaToX, MetaToY)
[ToX, ToY] = _square2point(MetaToX, MetaToY)
print(ToX, ToY)
event.widget.move(pieceID, ToX - CurX, ToY - CurY)

def _onPieceClick(event):
stuffTags = event.widget.gettags(event.widget.find_closest(event.x, event.y))
try:
    event.widget.delete(event.widget.find_withtag('bbox'))
except:
    pass
bboxULX = (event.x // 90 + 1) * 90
bboxULY = (event.y // 90 + 1) * 90 
bboxLRX = (event.x // 90 + 1) * 90 - 90
bboxLRY = (event.y // 90 + 1) * 90 - 90
event.widget.create_rectangle(bboxULX,bboxULY,bboxLRX,bboxLRY, width=3,   
outline='yellow',tag='bbox')
currentCommand = stuffTags[0]
print(currentCommand)`
```

The idea was to store the game piece tag in `currentCommand`, and then use that value to control that specific piece until the piece was moved with bindings like this:

```
canvas.bind('<1>', _newSpaceChosen)
```

in the `def __init__(self, mainWin):` of a `class Board(Canvas):`
Each piece has it's own `tag_bind(#piece-var, '<1>', _onPieceClick)`

My hypothesis is that `currentCommand` is not receiving a value soon enough.
What do you guys think causes this trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hypothesis is almost certainly correct. You can easily test this hypothesis by printing out the value before calling `find_withtag`.

Comment: Yeah, I had no idea the order the tkinter events took place, so I called `currentCommand` before I actually set it to anything. Thanks!